# Bold part of a string in React

Tags: html, reactjs

```
<li>No more boredom while studying. Get ready to have <b>lots of fun</b> 
   while learning.</li>
```

This `<b>` is not bolding the text inside, do I need to add anything else to it?

Comment: use `<strong> lots of fun</strong>` or `<b> lots of fun</b>` tags

Comment: The referenced dupe has nothing to do with OP's question. He does have b-tags and is using react. Should be reopened or a suitable dupe should be referenced.

Answer (score -1):

`<strong>This will be bold</strong>`